# Get cell style from excel spreadsheet with C#

Tags: c#, excel, coding-style, cell

Im trying to copy some cells from one workbook-sheet to another workbook-sheet and preserve the style and formatting using C#.

I can get the attributes one by one like this:

```
string fontName = ((Excel.Range) workSheet.Cells[3, 2]).Font.Name.ToString();
```

But Im looking for at way to get it all at once. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the cell(s) via the clipboard using the Range.Copy Destination:=  method then both the content and formatting will be copied. If you just want to copy the formatting use .Copy and then .PasteSpecial formats

Comment: Thanks. That is surly in the right direction.
Range1.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, Type.Missing, Type.Missing) will result in a picture that looks as it should, but well, it should not be a picture. If I change the PasteType to xlPasteColumnWidth it looks almoste right, but height and width is totally off. Any sugestions ?

Comment: If you want to copy both the cells content and formatting from one place to another place don't use pastespecial, just use the Copy Method of the Range object with the Destination parameter - Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy 
    destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")
If you just want to copy the formatting but not the content use copy and pastespecial Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C5").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D5").PasteSpecial _
        Operation:=xlPasteSpecialFormats
End With

Comment: When I use the copy method I get an error. Think it has something to do with me using multiple workbooks and sheets. I ended up using a hack where is use PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteColumnWidths, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); and manual set the ColumnWidth and RowHeight. Ugly but it works. Thanks for the help.